# ¿Como testear que cuando un dado saca un 10 vuelva a tirar?

Tags: php, while, phpunit

Tengo una función que lanza un dado de 10 caras (números del 1 al 10), la idea es que cuando el dado saque un 10 vuelva a tirar y sume el resultado, repitiéndose siempre que el dado vuelva a sacar un 10.

Hasta aquí no tengo ningún problema, la duda surge cuando quiero hacer un test de ese caso concreto en el que el dado saca un 10.
¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Adjunto código de la función en cuestión:

```
    public function lanzarDado()
{
    $dado = rand(1,10);
    $resultado = $dado;
    while($dado == 10)
    {
        $dado = rand(1,10);
        $resultado += $dado;
    }
    return $resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido al mundo de los mocks.

Lo que se hace en estos casos es proporcionar un "Mock" en vez de utilizar la función real.

Un mock no es mas que un remplazo de la función original donde puedes definir qué comportamiento tendrá para cada caso.

Para tu caso concreto podemos definir esta función que la primera tirada sacará un 10 y un 1 las siguientes tiradas

```
$callCounter = 0
function lucky_rand($low, $high) {
  if ($callCounter == 0) { return 10 }
  $callCounter++
  return 6
}
```

Con esto ya tenemos definido cómo queremos que se comporte. Ahora el problema viene, cómo hacemos que nuestro código utilice esta función?

Una posible forma es cambiar la firma de tu función:

```
public function lanzarDado($randFunction) {
```

De esta forma puedes pasarle la función que quieras utilizar cada vez. Y tiene bastante sentido si estás utilizando programación orientada a objetos. Porque seguramente tendrías un objeto Dado y otro objeto que es el que hace los lanzamientos. Así que a la hora de construir el segundo objeto puedes pasarle un mock de Dado.

Como no es tu caso, y cambiar las firmas no es siempre lo que quieres hacer. En PHP concretamente hay un truco muy divertido usando namespaces.

Esta es la parte de la documentación que nos interesa especialmente:

> PHP will fall back to global functions […] if a namespaced function
> […] does not exist.

`rand` es una función global. Cuando escribes `rand` PHP realmente está llamando a `Namespace\Where\You\Are\Now\rand()` y va subiendo cada namespace hasta llegar al global.

También puedes llamar la función de esta forma `\rand()` y no hará la búsqueda en tu namespace, pero ese detalle no nos interesa ahora ;)

Por lo que si tu función está dentro de un namespace (muy buena práctica en general) puedes crear un mock de una manera muy sencilla. En tu fichero de tests puedes re definir la función dentro de tu namespace:

```
namespace Namespace\Where\You\Are\Now {
    $callCounter = 0
    function rand($low, $high) {
      if ($callCounter == 0) { return 10 }
      $callCounter++
      return 6
    }
}
```

Ahora cuando llames a `rand` desde los tests (y por lo tanto desde tu función) siempre usará esta función en vez de la global.

Valga decir que hay muchos frameworks para trabajar con mocks que son mucho mas flexibles, ya que te permiten definir comportamientos de forma mucho mas simple...

Pero hace mucho que no toco PHP y no podría recomendarte uno concreto.

Comment: No te falta el $ en las variables?

Comment: @BetaM gracias! añadidos... no tengo un entorno de php montado a mano ya que hace varios años que no trabajo con php así que puede que al código le falten algunos retoques..

Comment: @nax He intentado redefinir la función rand en el namespace del fichero de test, pero me da el siguiente error: 

 `PHP Fatal error:  No code may exist outside of namespace {} in ...`

Es la primera vez que intento redefinir algo dentro de un namespace, no sé si lo estoy haciendo del todo bien.

`namespace test{
    function rand($low, $high) {
        $callCounter = 0;
      if ($callCounter == 0) { return 10; }
      $callCounter++;
      return 6;
    }
}`
Y bajo eso, el resto del código.

Comment: @Wiki 

He asumido que usas namespaces en el código.. pero si no es así esta técnica de mock no te funcionaría...

En tu código original deberías tener `<?php namespace Project\Class` y en el test usas el mismo namespace. De esa forma cuando lanzas el test tu función original usa la función declarada dentro del namespace pero en una ejecución normal usa solo la global.
Si lo defines en bloques entonces el resto del bloque debe estar también dentro de un namespeca